# Difference in using chrome mobile view in desktop and using chrome in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am working on an application which has a web view and a mobile view. For testing the mobile view I had used the chrome change to mobile display / tablet display option. But when I'm using the application in the mobile, there is a big difference. What am I missing ?

Comment: What 'big difference' is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the differences in between web view and mobile view when we test is that of the user agent. If you want to get the mobile experience in testing on google chrome, you should not just change the view from chrome to mobile / tablet. But you should probably also find a way to change the user agent itself. Else you can open the same uri on the mobile phone browser. That way the user agent remains the same.

Also certain actions in the mobile browser will be different from that of web browser. In a browser in mobile view you can expect `touch` based actions whereas in the other case on web browser you can expect click based actions.

Read more on user agent here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Also, you can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg to switch your user agent. We used that in a project although I do not know if it works well now.

Here's a reference on touch events: https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#event-touchstart

Comment: I think I will use the mobile only to test the application. It is a more real representation of the use case. Thanks.